# What is the difference between factors and latent variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

From what I have read about factor analysis and latent variable models, factors and latent variables are, both unobserved, and both serve the purpose of shrinking the observed data to a smaller data set by compelling the observed data to be conditioned upon them so as to aid the modeling procedure.
My confusion is since both are accomplishing the same task then why are they treated separately in the literature?? Am I missing anything??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the factor analysis literature, "latent variable" and "common factor" are often treated as synonyms, as if the common factor is identical with the hypothetical excluded variable. However, an alternate view, inspired by a scientific realist philosophy of science, is that the excluded variable is a genuine entity existing independent of data, that the common factor is only a proxy for the latent variable, and that other techniques might also be used to construct different proxies for the latent variable. See [Rigdon (2012)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024630112000581) and [Rigdon, Becker, & Sarstedt (2019)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00273171.2018.1535420?casa_token=dAXTgIsORqUAAAAA:rL7BpmtNB2gQSU7AIX1gHAl768nI1gekERBHRbfbaYYAz1jOMLvJ7Qomy3uZ2njIJpYkr_fvTh-O).